# Hide updated pages menu from left navigation wiki pages library

Tags: 2013, navigation, wiki-pages

There is an additional updated pages menu shown in left navigation when I create and open wiki pages library.

It confuses the user that which is the real left navigation because it looks like there are 2 left navigations, is there any easy way to hide this?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to hide will be to select the div using its selectors like `ID` or `Class` and hide it using `CSS`. :)

```
.className{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```