# Hide Updated Pages list from left navigation wiki page but keep other list unhide

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I only want to hide "Updated Pages" list from left navigation wiki page but keep other lists such as "Home" unhide.

I tried to insert script editor with codes,

```
 <style>
 #DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar{
     display: none !important;
  }
  </style>
```

Then all left navigation is hidden which is not my expectation.

I also tried to understand solution of [Hide updated pages menu from left navigation wiki pages library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113908/hide-updated-pages-menu-from-left-navigation-wiki-pages-library) but cannot reach my expectation as well.

I'm a green hide on codes and your step-by-step illustration would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

That is right - now you are hiding entire left hand navigation (#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar).

You can use this CSS to hide only "Updated Pages" section:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

  .ms-quicklaunchouter{ display: none; } 

</style>
```

Comment: Hi @Jessica , if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a big fan of the separator line, I used this in Office 365 >> SharePoint Online to ditch it, put it either in your master page or per page in a content editor web-part:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

  .ms-quicklaunchouter{ display: none; } 
  .ms-core-listMenu-separatorLine{ display: none; }

</style>
```